# PHP string inception manipulation

Tags: php

I cant get this to work and its driving me mad, pls help

```
echo "<a href='#' onclick='javascript:$.jGrowl
(\"".$_SESSION['product_description'][$i]."\")' >?</a>";
```

the problem comes down to the 'product_description' - those single ' marks are breaking it, what should i do sigh

EDIT: if i replace the .$_SESSION['product_description'][$i]. with a bunch of charecters it works, its not a problem with anything but PHP and those ''

Comment: If you weren't missing the opening quote, what exactly isn't working? What does the output code look like?

Comment: David, what is your output? Does it actually output the value of `$_SESSION['product_description'][$i]`? Does it actually contain a value? Also, make sure to escape any double quotes that may exist in the value... See my updated answer...

Answer (score 2):

Chances are the **real** problem lies with the `$.jGrowl`. Within double quotes, PHP tries to parse found variables. e.g.

```
$foo = 'foo';
echo "This is foo: $foo"; // output: This is foo: foo
```

So, to avoid this you need to escape the `$` using `\$` within the string...

```
echo "...\$.jGrowl..."
```

[See this demo](http://www.ideone.com/DQr15).

---

*Keep this here for reference:*

Escape them with a backslash, like you would with double quotes. e.g.

```
// which ever quote is used to encapsulate the string
// must be escaped within the output.
echo 'Hello, \'world!\''; // output: Hello, 'world!'
echo "Hello, \"world!\""; // output: Hello, "world!"

// but, if you use the opposite quote, it does not need
// to be escaped for output.
echo 'Hello, "world!"';   // output: Hello, "world!"
echo "Hello, 'world!'";   // output: Hello, 'world!'
```

See the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) on strings for more information and what characters need escaping.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting T_STRING ...sigh

Comment: @David: [not for me](http://www.ideone.com/QkP3v). -- unless you mean in your code...

Comment: +1 for spotting the potential `$` tripping hazard - however, in this particular instance it shouldn't cause a problem, since `$.` is not a valid variable name (or start of a variable name).

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing your opening `"`?

```
echo "<a href='#' onclick='javascript:$.jGrowl(\"".$_SESSION['product_description'][$i]."\")' >?</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it

```
echo "<a href='#' onclick='javascript:$.jGrowl(\"".$_SESSION['product_description'][$i]."\")' >?</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo "<a href='#' onclick='javascript:\$.jGrowl(\"".str_replace('"','\"',$_SESSION['product_description'][$i])."\");' >?</a>";
```

You need to ensure you are escaping any double quotes within the value...

Comment: @David not for me on my machine, and not [here](http://www.developphp.com/php_syntax_validator/) either...

Comment: What is the value of `$_SESSION['product_description'][$i]`?

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me:

```
echo "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"javascript:$.jGrowl('".$_SESSION['product_description'][$i]."')\" >?</a>";
```